# Sort a table based on a column with string mixed with numbers in bash

Tags: bash, sed, sorting, awk

I have a txt file with the below table

```
3-6-13  0.0712  ./13-t.xyz
3-6-13  0.0717  ./2-t.xyz
3-6-13  0.3737  ./6-t.xyz
3-6-13  0.5862  ./5-t.xyz
3-6-13  0.7503  ./4-t.xyz
```

how can I sort it based on the third column as:

```
3-6-13  0.0717  ./2-t.xyz
3-6-13  0.7503  ./4-t.xyz
3-6-13  0.5862  ./5-t.xyz
3-6-13  0.3737  ./6-t.xyz
3-6-13  0.0712  ./13-t.xyz
```

unfortunately I can't use the -v option of sort;

```
sort -v -k 3 out.tmp
```

any other solution by awk sed or etc?

Comment: Why can't you use the `-V` (it's capital V in my version of sort)?

Comment: Curious: Which/What OS are you using, Ubuntu/Debian has no "-v" in sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Schwartzian transform: extract the number to a separate field, sort it, then remove it

```
$ sed -r 's/(.*\/)([0-9]+)/\2 \1\2/' table.txt | sort -n -k1,1 | cut -d" " -f2-
3-6-13  0.0717  ./2-t.xyz
3-6-13  0.7503  ./4-t.xyz
3-6-13  0.5862  ./5-t.xyz
3-6-13  0.3737  ./6-t.xyz
3-6-13  0.0712  ./13-t.xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sort --numeric-sort --ignore-leading-blanks -k3.3 "${File}"
```

Refer: Key from `man sort`

## Output

```
3-6-13  0.0717  ./2-t.xyz
3-6-13  0.7503  ./4-t.xyz
3-6-13  0.5862  ./5-t.xyz
3-6-13  0.3737  ./6-t.xyz
3-6-13  0.0712  ./13-t.xyz
```